# Which MiniRedirector function is called for |FlushFileBuffers(handle_to_volume)|?

Tags: winapi

We're implementing a new filesystem via Win32 MiniRedirector.
In one scenario we want to flush the filesystem - but if we call |FlushFileBuffers(handle_to_volume, opened with ".\T:", for volume T:)| with Adminstrator privileges, no function in the redirector seems to be called.

Is this the expected behaviour, or can the MiniRedirector see the |FlushFileBuffers()| ?

Comment: [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) explains how markdown works at SO.